# Produce tree output with Surefire like the JUnit 5 console launcher

Tags: java, junit5

The [Console Launcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher) that comes with JUnit Platform (from JUnit 5) produces a quite nice summary view at the end. The Maven Surefire plugin, however, has a very simple output.

Is it possible to create with Surefire output similar to what the launches creates?

Comment: A really good answer can be found down below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978707/2621917

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's an old topic, but this topic was the reason I've developed this extension 2 years ago: https://github.com/fabriciorby/maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter

Basically, to get your tree output, add this to your pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.fabriciorby</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
        <consoleOutputReporter>
            <disable>true</disable>
        </consoleOutputReporter>
        <statelessTestsetInfoReporter
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoTreeReporterUnicode">
        </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[And the magic happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttL1e.png)

Comment: Hot! Would add more votes here and retract upvotes from the other answers, if only I could.

Comment: Thank you, Fabricio, really nicely done.

Comment: Arrived here via Medium, can confirm this does indeed bring the magic - a nice tree listing of all tests :)

Answer (score 5):

My current workaround is to disable surefire and use `exec-maven-plugin` to manually run `ConsoleLauncher`:

```xml
<!-- disable surefire -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version><!-- ... --></version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-test</id>
      <phase>none</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<!-- enable ConsoleLauncher -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version><!-- ... --></version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher</mainClass>
        <arguments>
          <argument>--scan-class-path</argument>
          <argument>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</argument>
        </arguments>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-console-standalone</artifactId>
  <version><!-- ... --></version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I love it. Not sure whether this is a good replacement in general (tools parsing test results and such), but definitely worth an extra goal for manual viewing. Or in addition.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Surefire is developig extensions [1](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/pull/226) for embedded Surefire features, and a standalone extension supporting JUnit5 DisplayName.
One of these extensions is a console logger of testset information. Very similar output to the console in [2](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher) might be possible to support as well then.

The extensions is a set of Java abstractions and Surefire/Failsafe plugins will contain default implementations of these abstractions. The other progressive extension implementations, with the output like in [2](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher), would kindly require users to support Surefire project to implement the extensions in their own GitHub repositories (not in ASF). Surefire is welcome to list all third party implementations of these extensions on the ASF Maven Surefire webpage.

This way (Open-Closed DP) we believe we would provide you with certain freedom to change the behavior of plugins without reporting real Jira issues and without waiting for a new feature release.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Feel free to open a feature request to extend the current summary output at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE/issue and perhaps a Pull Request against https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire ;-)

Comment: This answer would count as a ‘no’ then.

Comment: Yes.
But it is not impossible to implement.