# Output in a Maven plugin when loaded via `ServiceLoader`

Tags: maven-plugin, junit5

In a vain attempt to solve [Produce tree output with Surefire like the JUnit 5 console launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722888) for myself, I added a simple JUnit Jupiter `TestExecutionListener` to my project. It is registered via putting the class name into some file in `META-INF`, so I assume it is using Java’s `ServiceLoader`. In any case, it is instantiated with the default constructor.

Now the tricky integration part: When run using Surefire, all writes to standard out trigger warnings – this is not the way Maven plugins are supposed to create output. However, in the default-constructed listener, how would I get access to the Maven logger?

Maybe it is easier to extend Surefire and instead somehow wire the listener into it?